# New code Lines in c# project is not executed

Tags: c#

I`m a new guy to c# and I try to add a some code to a certain class in my c# project in order to remove some characters from a string. These lines of codes are **not executed** at run time and the debugger steps over it.So,

**1)** How to make the new lines added to an existing project execute?

**2)** Is there a property in Visual studio 2005 that prevents developers from changing existing code?

**3)** Is it some Property related to the c# project that specifies a privilege of code change?

Comment: Please post the code so we can help.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning solution and rebuilding? Is build output being placed in the 'usual' place? Is the code you altered in a separate project (and ref by dll) and not being rebuilt?

Comment: There is no special code...if I add any line of code or chanage any existing code, then the changes will not be executed.

I tried Rebuild Solution, but it didn`t work.

what you mean by Bulid output placed in usual place?

Comment: There is nothing to discuss until you post the offending code.

Comment: I have my code like this: 
string sMailMsg = eMailMsg.ToString(); 
I want to change it to: 
string sMailMsg = eMailMsg.ToString().Replace("\0", string.Empty); //This part of change '.Replace("\0", string.Empty)' is not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure you are not returning the a value before the added lines.  If you hit a return prior to getting to those new lines that will exit the function and your new code will never execute.

Comment: This is not happening. I make changes on any existing code, but the changes is not executed at runtime. That`s it my friend.

Comment: try this:  Copy your bin folder to another location and then delete the contents of it.  then rebuild your project.  Check the bin folder to make sure all your components were compiled and then run the debugger and see what happens.  If the build fails your bin folder will not have all your dll's.  Oh an restarting the computer never hurt either (=.

Answer (score 1):

you should try cleaning your project and rebuilding it, sometimes visual studio is stupid and does not rebuild all the assemblies.  i find that this fixes this problem about 80% of the time (if it's not my code, that is)

Comment: How to clean a C# project and there is not tool under Build Menu to do so?

Comment: Right-click on the project (or the solution file) in the Solution Explorer. There should be a "clean" option there.

Comment: you can use that tool, or you can use the OS to delete the obj and bin folders.  deleting these folders is more aggressive, and should only be done AFTER trying the built-in tool.  also, there are powershell scripts around the interwebs that can be used.

Answer (score 1):

1) Just rebuild entire solution

2) No, as far as I know

3) No, as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned string, are you assigning the output back to the variable?

E.g.

```
string aStr = "   abcdefg   ";
aStr = aStr.Trim();
```

If you only do `aStr.Trim()`, you won't see the "update".

Comment: I have my code like this:
string sMailMsg = eMailMsg.ToString();
I change it to:
string sMailMsg = eMailMsg.ToString().Replace("\0", string.Empty);

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger and tell us what the old value (i.e. eMailMsg.ToString() ) is?

Comment: The old value of eMailMsg.ToString() is: 
\r\nTest\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\r\n"

Answer (score 0):

"\0" has a particular meaning in C# strings. Are you actually trying to remove the null character, or are there literal backslashes and zeroes?

If you're trying to remove a backslash and then a zero, try this instead:

```
string sMailMsg = eMailMsg.ToString().Replace("\\0", string.Empty);
```

Comment: The sintex of the code is not my problem. my problem is that. Any change to my code is not executed at runtime.